# How to remove IBL from scene

Tags: lighting

Was curious how one might go about NOT using an hdri and image based lighting in a scene. For example if you wanted to have a static value for an ambient light value and then use only direct lighting from various light sources, vs having the ambient light value based off of one of the hdri images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to correct me, but I think you want something like this. The setup below keeps the HDRI image, but removes it's light influence. Instead, you can influence the background value using a Value node connected either to the Color or the Strength input. The trick is to separate the light influence from the background image using the *Is Camera Ray* output of a *Light Path* Node.

[image: Light]

Comment: I do believe this would do the trick! Then if I didn't want the background image to display at all I just wouldn't link it to the mix shader. Is that correct?

Comment: If you don't want any HDRI (lighting or image), omit the mix shader, light path and image, and just connect it like _Value > Background > World Output_

Comment: This works beautifully! Greatly appreciated.